# How do you use CSS events with jQuery styling?

Tags: jquery

```
// Doesn't work:   
$('#king:hover').css({});
```

Title explains all. Is this Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.hover` [event](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('#king').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','black');
});
```

If you want to remove it on hover release, you can use a second handler

```
$('#king').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
    }, function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

Or better yet, use `toggleClass`

**CSS**

```
.hover {
    background-color:black;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#king').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```